# Apache won't rewrite URLs containing a file in the request path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've isolated an odd case with mod_rewrite on a standard Apache install. Consider a Rule that rewrites all requests to a file called `test.html` at the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

`test.html` is the only file in the filesystem.

Here's what happens when I make some requests:

```
Request                   |   Result              | Status
----------------------------------------------------------
example.com/test.html     | example.com/test.html | 200
example.com/foo           | example.com/test.html | 200
example.com/foo.html      | example.com/test.html | 200
example.com/foo/bar       | example.com/test.html | 200
example.com/foo/bar.html  | example.com/test.html | 200
example.com/test/bar      | [error Not Found]     | 404
example.com/test/bar.html | [error Not Found]     | 404

Error messages for the last two requests:
The requested URL /test.html/bar was not found on this server
The requested URL /test.html/bar.html was not found on this server.
```

I've tried all sorts of RewriteRules but I cannot prevent the errors, without physically adding a new directory named `test`.

Why does this happen?

Is there some way to override this behavior?

Comment: Crystal ball wild guess: this smells like [type maps/content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/content-negotiation.html), which can lead to IMO utterly surprising behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in `.htaccess` to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Comment: That did it!

When you say "If the server receives a request... etc." Are you describing what happens when Multivews is enabled?

Comment: Yes that's it. In your case it is necessary to disable it.